# I am a recorder player and have come across a strange version, would like to know more

Tags: fingering, recorder

[image]
[image]

Any ideas what this might be called, note the thumb hole is in the lower end of the tube.
Thanks

Comment: ... Meanwhile, David, check out [this thread](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/722/how-to-write-an-acceptable-instrument-equipment-identification-question): It would help, and make it a more useful question, if you could tell anything about the context in which you found it, or ask for input on its playing technique or the music it's used in. Also, you can ask in the chat room; I'm personally curious to know the answer.

Comment: @AndyBonner It's a poorly made fipple flute which could have been made anywhere in the world. These kind of flutes are often sold to tourists, it will sound somewhere between a recorder and a tin whistle but the intonation will be bad because the tone holes are poorly placed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the expertise to name this flute with any kind of confidence, but the placements of the holes resembles that of a [kaval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaval). Kavals are typically end blown though, meaning that there is no mouthpiece except for a sharp edge at the end of the pipe. A web search for "fipple kaval" gives some results though, so it might help you find more information.

The holes at the bottom are sometimes called [devil's holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaval#Playing), and are not meant to be fingered. They change the timbre of the lowest notes and play an important part in the kaval sound. I would guess the holes of your flute serve the same function, so trying to play really softly in the lowest register you might find interesting sounds.

Comment: It's not a kaval. If it were the finger holes would be much closer together (chromatic rather than diatonic) and there would be seven of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not every hole on the back of a fipple flute is a thumb hole, unless you have very long and flexible thumbs. If that hole is for anything, it's to correct the intonation by making the tube effectively shorter.
Not knowing where this flute came from, I can't guess what it would be called. Though @AndyBonner is probably right, it's tourist gift shop flute.